# Inserting Facebook plugin on mediawiki

Tags: facebook, mediawiki

I am trying to get the Facebook plugin working on my wiki. Using the guidelines provided by Facebook I copied the Java Script SDK in MediaWiki:Common.js, which should run it for all users.

Now I am trying to enter the simple HTML code also generated by Facebook :

```
<div id="Facebook" class="fb-page" data-href="(my FB page)" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false"></div>
```

'My FB page' is of course replaced by the actual URL.

I tried two ways of entering the code.

1. Making a Template:Facebook page and linking to it like {{Facebook}} on the actual page
2. Even though this is not recommended forcing the html by adding the parameter $wgRawHtml = true; and entering the code in the ... tags.

None of this ways resulted in the Facebook plugin appearing on my wiki.

Comment: does the js and html code render? If it does, any console messages?

Comment: no, the html code is simply ignored

Comment: And is `$wgUseTidy` by any chance on?

Comment: Also, I would strongly recommend against using `wgRawHtml`. You can write a simple parser extension that inserts your code instead, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions

Comment: Actually: You _should_ be able to insert a div even without `$wgRawHtml`. Are you sure it is ignored? Do you have a link?